# Python IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, indexing

I try to develop scorecard risk model with this code:

```
 scorecard_train = X_train[coefficients.index].apply(lambda x: x*coefficients['cf'].T,axis=1)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-156-06a4182aee37> in <module>
----> 1 scorecard_train = X_train[coefficients.index].apply(lambda x: x*coefficients['cf'].T,axis=1)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `coefficients.index` is one of those things? If not, you'll probably need to add an extra line of code to convert it into one of those things. Unless `coefficients['cf']` is the problem, but as presented it looks like a normal `dict` and thus is probably not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by taking out [coefficients.index]

```
scorecard_train = X_train_df.apply(lambda x: x*coefficients['cf'].T,axis=1)
```